# How can I prevent GNU Emacs from splitting windows on startup?

Tags: window, customize

Whenever I try to open an existing file with GNU Emacs, the window always split horizontally so as to show two buffers: one buffer containing the file and the *GNU Emacs* buffer. How can I set up Emacs to not do that and show only the buffer that holds the file's text?

Comment: Not sure I'm following, but I'm not getting this behavior out of the box.  Try `emacs -Q`: does it still split the frame into two windows?  If not, it's something in your init file.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, I think it's probably something in my `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the following in your init file:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

or, equivalently, say

```
M-x customize-variable RET inhibit-startup-screen RET
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter -- I don't get the splitting behavior when using `emacs -q` (same as `-Q`, except still has the splash screen) either.